# Relationship between body size and damage done by electricity

Tags: electrophysiology, electromuscular

We all know that if a person gets stunned by a 2000 volt stun gun, he/she may be knocked unconscious, but he/she is still alive and apparently no damage done on his/her body.

But what could happen if that 2000 volt is applied to a snail whose body is way smaller than that of a human being? 
Will it create a lot of damage into the snail's body?
Or the same effect as that of humans.

Comment: Certainly it will be more. When a person gets stunned by a 2000 volt stun gun the electricity spreads into whole body. If the target is large the damage would decrease (as you see in humans it has no serious damage) but if the body is smaller, the damage will be greater.